# Tomcat threads stuck reading payload from client

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, servlets, networking, servlet-3.0

Our application server runs on Tomcat with default connector and 200 threads. Usually on an average any given time only 4-10 threds are busy, however noticed that at one point all 200 threads were busy. After analyzing the thread dump, found that all threads are busy reading from client. Need guidance on understanding the thread dump and any lead. Thanks

The http thread were stuck in 2 similar stack trace (pasted A and B below). Threads with stack A were count of 171 and stack with thread B were 29. A group threads does not have application in the trace and B group thread traces does have application classes (XZYServlet).

> I think that it is due to slow network and hence threads are busy reading post payload. Any other clues ?

1. Since we are running with 200 threads, shouldn't all threads be stuck with application classes in trace ? i.e B type thread stack
2. Any idea why threads are stuck with trace of type A ?
3. Any other reasons why all threads would be stuck with that stack trace ?
4. Since we have multiple servlets, I was thinking to allocate limited number of threads per servlet to solve such issues where all threads are busy serving 1 servlet. However since not all threads are stuck in servlet, I am not sure. Any other ideas or possible options to address such issues ?

> A) Trace with no Application classes

```
http-bio-8000-exec-244" #5779 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9d68010800 nid=0x31e9 runnable [0x00007f9d165c5000] (171 thread)
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:526)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:511)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:168)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1010)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        - locked <0x00000007bf5c99b8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> B) Trace with application classes in stack (XZYServlet)

```
http-bio-8000-exec-250" #5785 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9d68091800 nid=0x31ef runnable [0x00007f9d157b8000] (29 Thread)
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:542)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:511)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:573)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:287)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadChars(InputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.substract(CharChunk.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.read(CoyoteReader.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1485)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1461)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:602)
    at com.ParserUtils.getJsonObject(ParserUtils.java:500)
    at com.XZYServlet.doGet(XZYServlet.java:156)
    at com.XZYServlet.doPost(XZYServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    - locked <0x00000007bfb43350> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What are the clients doing?  If, for example, they are a websocket then I would expect them to be waiting.

Comment: Clients are not websockets in this case. They are calling our url with post call, header containing content-length and post body.